# How do I upload image in Flutter App to my server and decode the json response from the server?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an Endpoint on my server which accepts multipart/form-data and sends back json as a response.
I want to send an Image from my flutter App to my server and Decode the json received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http.MultipartRequest for that

Example:-

```
  static Future<UploadImageRes> uploadImage(int id, File imageFile) async {
    if (imageFile != null) {
      var stream = new http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
      var length = await imageFile.length();
      String token = PreferenceUtils.getString(AppConstants.LOGGED_IN);
      var uri = Uri.parse(UrlConstants.ADD_RECIPE_PHOTO);

      LogUtils.d("====uri :   $uri");
      LogUtils.d("====recipeId :   $id");

      var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      String fileName = imageFile.path.split("/").last;
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('photo', stream, length,
          filename: fileName, contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg'));

      request.headers.addAll({"Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      request.fields["recipeId"] = "$id";

      var response = await request.send();
      var statusCode = response.statusCode;

      LogUtils.d("====statusCode :   $statusCode");

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 400) {
        throw new ApiException("Uploading failed");
      }

      final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      return Future.value(UploadImageRes.fromJson(JsonDecoder().convert(respStr)));

    } else {

      throw new ApiException("Uploading failed");

    }

  }
```

In `final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();` you will get your api response